# start /affinity parameter not work on ffmpeg in some situation

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cpu, task-manager

I want to use `start /affinity` to reduce cpu usage of ffmpeg, but it doesn't work in some situation.

This will work:

`start /low /affinity 1F ffmpeg -i a.mp4 b.mkv`

This will not work:

`start /low /affinity 1F ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset fast -x265-params crf=21 -c:a copy b.mkv`

`/low` parameter works in both commands, but `/affinity` not.